# Errors of turning question mark（‘？’） into NaN while imputing a machine learning data

Tags: machine-learning, missing-data, imputation

I am trying to impute all missing data (as indicated by a '?') into `NaN` and use the imputation tool from `sklearn` to average them into a mean value. To be reproducible on my problem, I have included my code as below: I use **PyCharm as IDE, Mac OS X and anaconda on Py 2.7.12**

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/communities/communities.data', header=None, sep=',\s', na_values=["?"])
df.tail()
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imr = Imputer(missing_values='NaN', strategy='mean', axis=0)
imr= imr.fit(df)
```

And here is my error message

```
 /Users/zdong/anaconda/bin/python/Users/zdong/PycharmProjects/ml/crim_workingfile.py
```

> ```
> /Users/zdong/PycharmProjects/ml/crim_workingfile.py:4: ParserWarning:   Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex); you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
> ```

```
df = pd.read_csv('http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning databases/communities/communities.data', header=None, sep=',\s', na_values=["?"])
```

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/Users/zdong/PycharmProjects/535_final/535_workingfile.py", line 8,
> in <module>
> imr= imr.fit(df)
>   File "/Users/zdong/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/imputation.py",
> line 156, in fit
> force_all_finite=False)
>   File "/Users/zdong/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py"
> line 382, in check_array
> array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)
> ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 6,?,?,Ontariocity,10,0.2,0.78,0.14,0.46,0.24,0.77,0.5,0.62,0.4,0.17,0.21,1,0.4,0.73,0.22,0.25,0.26,0.47,0.29,0.36,0.24,0.28,0.32,0.22,0.27,0.25,0.29,0.16,0.35,0.5,0.55,0.16,0.47,0.58,0.53,0.2,0.6,0.24
> ```

Please help me the devastated beginner QAQ...

Comment: I don't know anything about sklearn in particular, but the error you're getting is because it's trying to convert to a float array, and can't convert '?' to one. 'NaN' would be fine, so maybe just convert all '?' to that before parsing?

Comment: @Iluvatar Thank you... How could I convert these '?' into NaN? Sorry... I know this question is a bit silly...

Comment: Ah, I see you used `na_values=["?"]`, so it should catch that. It may be that your `sep` is `',\s'`, but it looks like it's purely a CSV you have there (no spaces between commas). If that's the case, then it would take the whole line as a single column.

Comment: @Iluvatar Uhhh!!! Thank you! Now that I removed my `sep` part on Imputer, and got a much less complicated error message: `ValueError: could not convert string to float: Ontariocity`... Although I have no idea how to fix it, it seems this is a good step forward...

Comment: Well yes, I don't know what that's doing in a line of numbers, but it certainly can't be converted to a float. Is it a column in the CSV that you don't use for data?

Comment: @Iluvatar You mean the column with `Ontariocity` there? Hmmm... It is the name of the county... I think it is ok to get rid of them if I have to, but I wonder if there is a way to keep them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I think there's enough here for an actual answer. Looking at your data, the first 5 columns look like info about the cities (name, other values >= 1), and the rest look like the data you're interested in for the `fit` you do on the last line.

Your issue is that the fit tries to cast all the data to a float, and obviously fails on the city names. The data passed into the fit should probably be everything except the first 5 columns (maybe 4, if column 5 is the bias?). Either way, try something like:

```
df = pd.read_csv('communities.data', header=None, na_values=["?"], usecols=range(5, 128))
```

and change the 5 depending on which columns you need.